# デバイスの画面に応じて用意する3種類の画像サイズの考え方

Tags: swift, spritekit

現在言語はswiftでspritekitを使用してアプリ開発を進めようとしています。
そこで画像についてなのですが、使用する画像のサイズはデバイスによって変えなければならなく、xcodeでは@1x、@2x、@3xの３つの画像を用意するとデバイスに対応した画像のサイズを選んでくれますが、みなさんはどのようにして３つの画像を用意していますか？
ちなみに私は、画像を作る時はファイアアルパカとかいうお絵描きツールを使います。
画像を作る際は大きめに作って@3x用にして縮小して@2x、@1xに合うサイズに変更して使用しようと考えています。
問題はないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

通常は、大きめの画像を用意しておいて、そこから縮小して@1x、@2x、@3xを作成するというやり方で、特に問題ないと思います。

それぞれの画像のサイズは、@1xのサイズが基本で@2xだと2倍、@3xだと3倍のサイズになります。自分の場合、元の画像は1024x1024程度の大きさで用意しておいて、それぞれの大きさに縮小して使用しています。

例：@1xで40x40のサイズの画像を使用する場合

- @1x　→　1024x1024を40x40に縮小して画像を生成
- @2x　→　1024x1024を80x80に縮小して画像を生成
- @3x　→　1024x1024を120x120に縮小して画像を生成

いわゆる、ドット絵と言われるような画像を使用する場合なら、逆に@1xのサイズで元の画を用意して、それを単純に拡大することで@2x、@3xを生成するという方法も良いかも知れません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます＾ー＾
安心しました。
ちなみに@1x用、@2x用、@3x用の画像の作成時に大きさはどのように合わせていますか？
@3x画像を作ったとして@3x用の大きさからどれだけ小さくすれば@2xと@1x用端末の画面の大きさに合った画像が作れるとかはありますか？それとも目視で合わせる感じでしょうか？

Comment: 回答のほうに、サイズに関する説明を追加しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
画像は１つだけ用意して@3xで作れば@2x、@1xは自動で倍率を下げてくれるんですね。
感謝します！

Comment: いまいち、説明が通じてないような気がしますが・・・　@1x、@2x、@3xで3種類の画像を用意する必要がありますよ。環境に合わせて、どれを使うかを自動で選んでくれるだけです。

Comment: すみません。
@3x用に作った画像を、@2x用に３分の２にした画像を作り、@1x用に３分の１にした画像を作ればいいということですか？

Comment: 回答のほうに、もう少し具体的なやり方を追加しました。

Comment: わざわざありがとうございます。
理解できました＾ー＾
ちなみにseeさんは、縮小する時は何を使って縮小していますか？

Comment: 色々使いますけど、最近はgimpが多いですね。

Comment: ありがとうございました！参考にします！